# Recursive partitioning: Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: programming, recursion

Consider the following function, which recursively splits a list into equal length sublists (the length of the list is assumed to be a power of the second argument):

```
repPartition[list_, n_]:=
  If[Length[list]<=n, list, repPartition[Partition[list, n], n]]
```

This function does what it is intended to do. However the recursion probably doesn't make this the fastest possible; also I have the feeling that I've probably missed a built-in function which allows me to do this directly.

Therefore my question: Can this definition be improved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `Nest`:

```
ClearAll[nestedPartition];
nestedPartition[list_, n_] :=
  With[{depth = Log[n, Length[list]]},
     Nest[Partition[#, n] &, list, depth - 1] /; IntegerQ[depth]
  ];
```

For example

```
nestedPartition[Range[32],2]
```

Comment: This is at most just as fast as the recursive function.

Comment: @paw Well, it doesn't have the `$RecursionLimit` limitation, for one thing. The speed can't be very significantly improved simply because, for most actual use cases, the main time will be spent inside `Partition`, in both cases.

Comment: I think it's save to assume that the OP doesn't want to partition a list bigger then 2^1024.

Comment: I didn't know that you can put the condition inside a `With`. That's a nice way to get a restriction to valid lists. This alone is already a nice improvement to my version.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, `nestedPartitionShifrin[Range@160, 2]` is different from `nestedPartitioncEltschk[Range@160, 2]`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, `nestedPartitionShifrin[Range@n, 2]` is same as `nestedPartitioncEltschk[Range@n, 2]` only when $n=2^b$

Comment: @Tangshutao That's intentional. Have a closer look at the question as formulated by the OP.

Comment: @celtschk Shared variables (between the body and the condition) is a nice way to use the pattern-matcher, because it allows you to do some computation, and only then determine the fact of the match. If the condition doesn't hold, the pattern-matcher considers the rule not matched, pretending that those computations inside never happened. So, it will go on trying further rules, if the function has some more rules defined. I use this construct all the time.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I got it.:D Namely,`(the length of the list is assumed to be a power of the second argument)`.In that case, your algorithm is much faster.

Comment: @Tangshutao It is not really faster, but it avoids recursion.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
repPartition2[list_, n_] := 
  ArrayReshape[list, Table[n, {IntegerExponent[Length[list], n]}]]
```

Comment: Looks great. The [ArrayReshape documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) says introduced in 9.0, but unfortunately I'm stuck with 8.0, so I can't use that :-( But a +1, because I think this would actually be the perfect solution if only I could use it ...