# Where can I put my conditions?

Tags: programming

I just learned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61092/129) that you can put conditions inside a `With` and thus use computed values in them, like this:

```
f[x_] := With[{y = x^2}, y-2 /; y > 2]
f[2]
(*
==> 2
*)
f[1]
(*
==> f[1]
*)
```

A few tests show that it also works with `Module` and `Block`, and also in cases like this:

```
g[x_] := Module[{y=x}, Print["Test"]; y /; y == 1]
```

On the other hand, the following does *not* work:

```
SetAttributes[myblock,HoldAll]
myblock[v1_, v2_, expr_] := Block[{v1 = v2}, expr]
foo[x_] := myblock[a, x^2, a-1 /; a >= 1]
foo[0]
(*
==> -1 /; a >= 1
*)
```

Therefore I wonder: What are the exact rules where the condition can be put?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your last example does not work is that the condition is only interpreted as shared between the body and the signature, when it *literally* appears within `Block`, `Module`, or `With` *at the time the definition is created*. In your last example, you effectively postpone the insertion of `Condition` until run-time, into your newly defined scoping construct, and therefore this doesn't work (because the pattern matcher fails to recognize this as a conditional rule, see below).

In [my implementation of `LetL` macro](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with/10451#10451), I had to take this issue into consideration, which is why `LetL` was implemented as a macro (so it expands at run-time), and has a special definition for `SetDelayed`, to expand before `SetDelayed` actually creates a definition. A more detailed discussion in the context of `LetL` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition/5869885#5869885).

So, the moral of the story is that if you want to construct your own scoping constructs, which are equivalent to some nested combination of `Module`, `Block` or `With`, with the semantics of shared variables, then you *have to* expand that code at run-time to actual combination, before creating a definition (so that your scoping construct should then *necessarily* be a macro, rather than a normal function). And, you *can't* generalize this mechanism to a scoping construct with the head other than `With`, `Module` or `Block`, to be called at run-time with this semantics.

Heuristically, this can be easily understood, because such conditions with shared variables are treated specially by the pattern-matcher, but how would a pattern-matcher know that this is some such, looking only at the left-hand-side, if you have encoded such a construct into some user-defined head, which only evaluates when the r.h.s. of the rule evaluates? This is not possible.